# How long can I use a product-key version of Visual Studio 2015, offline?

Tags: visual-studio, license, visual-studio-2015, software-activation

**Background**

Our company is looking to start using Visual Studio 2015. We are planning to buy the perennial 5-license version of Visual Studio 2015 PROFESSIONAL. Our problem is that we have a bunch of machines here that cannot connect to the internet for extended periods of time.

**Question**

For how long will Visual Studio 2015 remain working (after the initial online-installation)?

Comment: normal use doesn't require internet. it should be good to go after initial setup as long as someone doesn't click on online help or news on start page. even then a small pause will be all the problem you'll have :)

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ Are you talking about professional?

Comment: what i said is version independent.